# TCP server ignores my SYN request from NET::RawIP

Tags: perl, networking, tcp

I use small perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Net::RawIP;

$a = new Net::RawIP({
        ip =>
            {
            daddr => '192.168.0.100'
            },

        tcp =>
            {
                source => 41218,
                dest => 80,
                syn => 1
            }
        });

$a->send;
```

and server doesn't send any response.

More detailed information from wireshark:
[screen](http://s27.postimg.org/ynzdkgw6b/Untitled.png)

I expected to get response from server. So, what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Validate the checksum, packets are dropped if the checksum is invalid